# FormGroup Directives

Tags: angular, formgroups

I want to ask why the form group directives are not case senstive?
in the constructor its written 'FormGroup' (as wel as initialization) while in the html tag directives is written as 'formGroup', I wonder if this a bug or perhaps it is intended to.

Thank you

Code Ref:
Constructor

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
...
export class EmployeeService {
constructor() { }
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({...})
```

HTML TAG DIRECTIVES

`<form [formGroup]="service.form" class="normal-form">`

I expect to be the same 'FormGroup' consistency between construction and html tag directives

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

[**`[formGroup]`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) that you use in the HTML Template and [**`FormGroup`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) that you use in the TypeScript Class are two different things.

[**`[formGroup]`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) that you use in the HTML Template is an Attribute Directive.

[**`FormGroup`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) that you use in the TypeScript Component Class is a Class.

There's no consistency in the names because these are the conventions that were followed by the Angular Team while creating them Directive Selectors and Classes.

Here's the [**Naming Convention to follow for the Directive Selectors**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-06) and the rationale behind it.:

> Do Use lower camel case for naming the selectors of directives.

Here's the [**Naming Convention to follow for the Class names**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-01) and the rationale behind it.:

> Do use upper camel case when naming classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code, the selector for the directive is given as `[formGroup]`

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts

code from the source:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[formGroup]',
    providers: [formDirectiveProvider],
    host: {'(submit)': 'onSubmit($event)', '(reset)': 'onReset()'},
    exportAs: 'ngForm'
})
export class FormGroupDirective extends ControlContainer implements Form
```